# How can I update a php variable in a Kohana view without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, ajax, kohana

I'm developing a web app using Kohana PHP framework and I got stuck. I set a PHP variable in my Controller to use it in a View. I would like to update this variable in the View continuously without refreshing the page. What I'd like to do is show a chart in real time using data from an SQL database where the curves' data is stored in this PHP variable. How can I do this? Is it possible to update this variable directly in the View (using my function in the Model)?

Comment: Send an XHR, that stores value in session. Thought, I kinda suspect that you are not aware that your HTML is not "view" anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an AJAX request with Javascript to your application without reloading the page. What happens is that the request is made to your controller/action, there you can query your database and you can pass back whatever your like. The AJAX request can retrieve the returning data and do something with it (in our case, replace some content with the new content).

You have to include this Javascript code on your page. In this example I use jQuery to make the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: /do/something  /* URL of your controller/action */
  success: function(data) { /* the data variable will receive the new content from the controller/action */
    $('#the_id_of_your_html_tag').html(data); /* replace the html content with the new data */
  },
});
```

In your Kohana controller you have something like this:

```
class Controller_Do extends Controller_Template
{
  public function action_something()
  {
    $this->auto_render = false;

     // make some call to your database, use your model whatever
     echo 'some string or variable';
     return;
  }
}
```

Your Html of your view will be like this (according to the example):

```
<div id="the_id_of_your_html_tag">something</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Can I return the variable only, Daan? Because what I'd like to do is not write something on the screen but use the data in my variable (which is a big array) to render a chart with a couple of curves. So instead of "echo 'some string or variable';" can I use "return $variable;" in the Controller and then in the Ajax' success part do something like "curves = <?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>;"? so that I can render the chart with jquery (jqplot)?

Comment: You can return whatever you like, arrays, json objects. In your case in the controller I would: "return json_encode($variable);" so you can directly use the json object in your success part of the javascript and render the chart with jquery jqplot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Daan! In the meantime I figured it out! :) What worked for me was: echo json_encode($variable); return;